# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

Tags: java, java-native-interface

Hello i'm writing a c++ code to call java functions from .jar class.

Here it is  :

```
#include <jni.h>
int main()
{
JavaVMOption options[1];
JNIEnv *env;
JavaVM *jvm;
JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
long status;
jclass JCTerminalClass;
jmethodID mid;
jobject obj;
char op0[] = "-Djava.class.path=C:\\Users\\DMNX1594\\Downloads\\jcop\\jcop/offcard.jar";
options[0].optionString =op0; 
vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
vm_args.nOptions = 1;
vm_args.options = options;

status = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);

if (status != JNI_ERR)
{
JCTerminalClass = env->FindClass("JCTerminal");
jthrowable exc;
exc = env->ExceptionOccurred();
if (exc) 
{
jclass newExcCls;
env->ExceptionDescribe();
env->ExceptionClear();
}

if(JCTerminalClass !=0)
{
mid = env->GetMethodID(JCTerminalClass, "com.ibm.jc.JCTerminal()", "()V");
      // Call here instance function later ...
} 
.
.
.
jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
return 0;
} else
return -1;
}
```

Compilation goes well, but during execution, i get the following :

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: JCTerminal
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: JCTerminal at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372) at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)

I already tried calling simple static java functions from a .jar that I created and it worked ! 
The code resembles a lot this one.

I tried setting the CLASSPATH environment variable to C:\path\to\jarFile\offcard.jar because i read that NoClassDefFoundError happens when the class is found during compiling but not during execution ...

Might it be a thread problem ?

Oh, and here's my compilation command : 
g++ -D __int64="long long" -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\include" -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\include\win32" -L"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\jre\bin\server" -L"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\lib" -o jni jni.cpp -ljvm

Thank you stackoverflowers :)

Comment: Are you sure it's not -cp for class path?

Comment: Do you mean in the compilation command ? -cp is for java compilation ...

Comment: it's also an argument for `java` command.

Comment: I'm sorry i didn't understand correctly your first comment.
What were you exactly suggesting ? thank you !

Comment: Never mind, I checked the docs - you're using the right option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your code fails on `JCTerminalClass = env->FindClass("JCTerminal");`

The documentation for JNIEnv->FindClass says this:

> `jclass FindClass(JNIEnv *env, const char *name);`
>
> [...]
>
> The name argument is a fully-qualified class name or an array type
>   signature . For example, the fully-qualified class name for the
>   `java.lang.String` class is: `"java/lang/String"`

However you are just passing the string `"JCTerminal"` without any package name. Later in your example you show the package name before the class name: `"com.ibm.jc.JCTerminal()"`
However in JNI code, the package name separator is not the dot (.) but the slash (/), as shown in the documentation above. So what you need to pass to the FindClass method is `"com/ibm/jc/JCTerminal"`:

```
JCTerminalClass = env->FindClass("com/ibm/jc/JCTerminal");
```

Comment: You were right eventually, i just forgot to put my .class files in the right directory ! I copied just the .class and not the folders that come before it in the directory tree !
Thank you !